# how can you make a multishot 10000 in minecraft 1.16?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So according to this video by phoenix sc:

.

You can make a crossbow that can shoot like millions of arrows and the command is in the description of the video which is :

```
give @p minecraft:crossbow{Enchantments:[{id:"minecraft:multishot",lvl:1s},
{id:"minecraft:quick_charge",lvl:5s}],ChargedProjectiles:[{id:"minecraft:arrow",Count:1b},
{id:"minecraft:arrow",Count:1b},{id:"minecraft:arrow",Count:1b}],Charged:1b}
```

Apparently, if you type in the command, the crossbow will only shoot 3 arrows. How can you fix this so it can turn into billions of arrows when shoot?

Comment: you can very clearly see he changes that command to increase the level throughout the video. it also seems like you need a datapack to use it

Answer (score 3):

According what PhoenixSC said during the video, **this effect simply isn’t achievable in standard Minecraft,** as it takes much modification to the behaviors of enchantments and the NBT tags. But, he created a vanilla data pack that allows this behavior and can be found [here](http://phoenixsc.me/download-links/datapacks/).

Comment: A datapack is vanilla Minecraft

Comment: @RayWu Ok, fixed that.